# Pig-Is there any maximum number of columns for which FILTER command be applied?

Tags: filter, apache-pig

I am having an input file which contains 952 columns. I would like to have a pig script which will check for schema not being altered. If altered, my script should fail. This is important because if the columns are altered or missing, my other pig script will fail, which is based on position of the column.

ie., $0 == 'browsername' ... $951 == 'state'.

```
a= LOAD '/user/a6000518-a/AdobeHourlySampleHeader/column_headers.tsv';
b= FILTER a BY (
$0 == 'accept_language' AND
$1 == 'browser' AND
$2 == 'browser_height' AND
$3 == 'browser_width' AND
...
$951 == 'state');
dump b;
```

My script fails when I apply filter on more than 625th position. I tried my script with each of the 50 columns in separate filters which works perfect. When I tried to use one filter for all 952 columns, it fails. Is there a better way to do this? Is this a limitation or somewhere my script could be wrong? Please advice.

Thanks!

[UPDATING WITH SCRIPT ERROR]

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. null
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.zip.Deflater.deflate(Deflater.java:419)
at java.util.zip.Deflater.deflate(Deflater.java:352)
at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.deflate(DeflaterOutputStream.java:251)
at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:211)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1876)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.write(ObjectOutputStream.java:1840)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1533)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:742)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
 ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing such a long statement, perhaps it would be better if you put that validation in a UDF. As for the exact reason why it is failing, I don't know since you haven't put the error it throws, but probably the parser cannot handle a statement that long.

To overcome this, write a UDF where you put a static array with the 952 values in order, and in the `FILTER` operation you call this UDF:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pig.FilterFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

public class MyFilter extends FilterFunc {
    private final static String[] FILTER_VALUES = {"accept_language", "browser", "browser_height"}; // Add all the values here in order

    @Override
    public Boolean exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
            if (!FILTER_VALUES[i].equals((String)input.get(i)))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

What this does basically is to iterate over all the values you pass to the UDF, and the moment a value is not equal to what you wrote in the array, it will return `false`, but if it all goes well it will return `true`.

To call this UDF, you need to register the jar with the UDF, define it, and pass all the values using `*` to it:

```
REGISTER myudfs.jar;
DEFINE MyFilter com.package.MyFilter(); 

a = LOAD '/user/a6000518-a/AdobeHourlySampleHeader/column_headers.tsv';
b = FILTER a BY MyFilter(*);
dump b;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Pasting the error message when I use Pig Filter method:

Comment: I tried this UDF approach and I am getting a cast exception: 2015-08-18 15:49:05,909 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias b. Backend error : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.pig.data.DataByteArray cannot be cast to java.lang.String.   In the stack trace, the error occurs in "if" condition where we are trying the cast bytearray into string.

Comment: I looked at different ways to cast databytearray into string but not yet fixed the error. Will you be able to help with?

Comment: I tried this code. But it doesn't output anything and no error. DataByteArray dba=new DataByteArray();
    
    try{ 
      for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
       dba.set(COLUMN_VALUES[i]);
          if (input.get(i)==null || !dba.equals(input.get(i)))
              return false;
        }
      
  }

Comment: @SathyaMageshKumar When you load the data without specifying the data type, it defaults to `DataByteArray`, which cannot be cast to `String`... Sorry about that, totally forgot it. One option is to specify the data in the loader, like `a = LOAD '/user/a6000518-a/AdobeHourlySampleHeader/column_headers.tsv' as (a:chararray,b:chararray...);`.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your previous UDF steps and I used LoadCaster to convert databytearray into string. Also reworked on return type to tuple with 952 fields if all column matches.

```
LoadCaster lc=new Utf8StorageConverter();
Tuple tup=TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(952);
@Override
public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

try{    
        for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
            DataByteArray dba=(DataByteArray)input.get(i);
            if(dba!=null){
                  if (!COLUMN_VALUES[i].equals(lc.bytesToCharArray(dba.get()))){
                          return tup;
                  }
                  else{
                  tup.set(i,COLUMN_VALUES[i]);
                  }
            }
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    return tup;
}
```

Pig Script:

```
register hdfs:///user/a6000518-a/ColumnDefinitionUDF.jar
a= LOAD '/user/a6000518-a/AdobeHourlySampleHeader/column_headers.tsv';
b= FOREACH a GENERATE ColumnDefinitionUDF.verify_columns(*);
dump b;
```

I am now able to get the desired output through Java UDF and it could be an alternative way to avoid defining datatype in Pig script for all 952 fields. Thanks @Balduz